# C# printing: how handing over printer settings

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have two forms:

```
  namespace Drucken
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void Print()
            {

                PrintDocument PrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

                Drucker DR = new Drucker(this);
                DR.ShowDialog();

                  PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = DR.SelectedSetting1.PrinterName;
                  PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = DR.SelectedSetting1.Copies;

                  // here i need the other printer settings [Color,PaperSize]...


                PrintDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
                PrintDoc.Print();
            }

            void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
            {           
               e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 100));
               e.Graphics.DrawString("Hier Steht ein Text.", new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(45, 45));

            }
            private void btnDrucken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Print();
            }


        }
    }
```

Form2:

```
namespace Drucken
{
    public partial class Drucker : Form
    {
        string Name1;
        int Anzahl1;
        PaperSize Papiergröße1;
        Form1 fh;
        private PrinterSettings m_SelectedSetting;
        public PrinterSettings SelectedSetting
        {
            get { return m_SelectedSetting; }
            set { m_SelectedSetting = value; }
        }
        public Drucker(Form1 aufrufer)
        {
            fh = aufrufer;
            InitializeComponent();
             m_SelectedSetting = new PrinterSettings();
        }        

        private void Drucker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbDrucker.DataSource = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().ToList<string>();
            cmbDrucker.SelectedItem = m_SelectedSetting.PrinterName;
            SetPrinter();
        }

        private void cmbDrucker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetPrinter();
        }

        private void SetPrinter()
        {
            PaperSize currentSize = cmbFormat.SelectedItem == null ? m_SelectedSetting.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize : (PaperSize)cmbFormat.SelectedItem;

            if (cmbDrucker.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                cmbFormat.DataSource = m_SelectedSetting.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().ToList<PaperSize>();
                cmbFormat.DisplayMember = "PaperName";
                cmbFormat.ValueMember = "PaperName";
            }

            cmbFormat.SelectedValue = currentSize.PaperName;


            if (m_SelectedSetting.MaximumCopies < Convert.ToInt16(nudExemplare.Value))
            {
                nudExemplare.Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(m_SelectedSetting.MaximumCopies);
                nudExemplare.Value = m_SelectedSetting.MaximumCopies;
            }

            if (m_SelectedSetting.DefaultPageSettings.Color)
                radFarbig.Checked = true;
            else
                radSchwarz.Checked = true;


        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                m_SelectedSetting.Copies = Convert.ToInt16(nudExemplare.Value);
                Anzahl1 = Convert.ToInt16(nudExemplare.Value);

                if (cmbDrucker.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    m_SelectedSetting.PrinterName = (string)cmbDrucker.SelectedItem;
                    Name1 = (string)cmbDrucker.SelectedItem;
                }

                if (cmbFormat.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    m_SelectedSetting.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = (PaperSize)cmbFormat.SelectedItem;
                    Papiergröße1 = (PaperSize)cmbFormat.SelectedItem;
                }

                if (radFarbig.Checked)
                    m_SelectedSetting.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;
                else
                    m_SelectedSetting.DefaultPageSettings.Color = false;

                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that i dont know how i get the printersettings [Color,PaperSize] (which i can choose in the secound form) into my form1, so that it is printing with the right settings...

**EDIT:**

```
PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = DR.SelectedSetting1.PrinterName;
PrintDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = DR.SelectedSetting1.Copies;
```

now i only need the other two settings [Color,PaperSize]

Comment: Add more public properties to your Drucker class.

Comment: please explain it more exactly!

Comment: Hard to see what needs to be explained.  You already have one public property, SelectedSetting.  You need two more so you can also return the paper size and the color.

Comment: but why do I need another two public propertys? "SelectedSetting" can return Printername,copies,Color,PaperSize,or not?